# Evaluate Boolean Expression

Tags: java, computer-science

I am having trouble understanding the answer to this question and wanted input from more experienced Java practitioners.

**Which of the following will evaluate to true only if boolean expressions** `A`, `B`, **and** `C` **are all false?**

(A) `!A && !(B && !C)`
(B) `!A || !B || !C`
(C) `!(A || B || C)`
(D) `!(A && B && C)`
(E) `!A || !(B || !C)`

My answer was D, since I was under the impression that *all* the boolean expressions were false, but the answer is C.

**Answer Explanation**

**(C)** In order for `!(A || B || C)` to be true, `(A || B || C)` must evaluate to false. This will happen only if `A`, `B`, and `C` are *all* false. Choice A evaluates to true when `A` and `B` are false and `C` is true. In choice B, if any *one* of `A`, `B`, or `C` is false, the boolean expression evaluates to true. In choice D, if any one of `A`, `B`, or `C` is false, the boolean expression evaluates to true since we have `!(false)`. All that's required for choice E to evaluate to true is for `A` to be false. Since `true||(any)` evaluates to true, both `B` and `C` can be either true or false.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: That "Answer Explanation" sounds like the explanation of the answer...

Comment: D is true whenever ANY of A, B or C is false but the question said: only when ALL of them are false.

Comment: The keyword in the question is **only if**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need some paraphrasing, and a more graphical explanation of what is going on.

**The Basics**

*Or*

The OR operator (`||`) outputs `true` if one of it's `operands` (things like `A`, `B`) are true. So in a truth table, that looks like this:

```
A   B   OUTPUT
f   f   f
f   t   t
t   f   t
t   t   t
```

**How this applies to you**

As you can see, the only way for the `OR` logic to output `false` is if all of the operands are false. The question states ***only if*** boolean expressions A, B, and C are all false?

The only one in that list that fits that criteria is indeed C. Let's work through an example:

```
Assume A, B and C = False.
// We'll now test if option C is the correct one.

C: !(A || B || C)
// Let's plug in our values.
C: !(False || False || False)
// And let's simplify it. False || False || False = False.
C: !(False)
C: True.
// Success! Now we need to test it when one of the values are true.

C: !(True || False || False)
// Let's simplify again. True || Anything = True.
C: !(True).
C: False.
```

Success! We now know that by changing one of the values, we've got `False`. Because it doesn't matter which one we've changed, we've proven by demonstration that `C` equates to `False` *iff (if and only if)* `A,B,C = False`.

**Why is it not D?**

Well let's look at the truth table for the `AND` logic.

```
A   B   OUTPUT
f   f   f
f   t   f
t   f   f
t   t   t
```

As you can see, the ONLY way for `AND` to output `true` is if all of the parameters are `true`, otherwise it will output false. While this means that D will evaluate to false, it will evaluate to false if `A`, `B` and `C` *contain* a false; whereas the question explicitly specifies that *all* of them must be false.

I hope this has helped!

Comment: The keyword in the question is **only if**. If the question was _"Which of the following will evaluate to true if boolean expressions A, B, and C are all false?"_, then D could be a correct answer.

Comment: I do apologise. It's getting quite late! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

`A && B && C` is true if and only if all of `A`, `B`, and `C` are true. If any of the variables are false, the whole expression is false. That means if any of the variables are false, `!(A && B && C)` is true.

`A || B || C` is true if any of the variables are true. It is only false if all the variables are false. That means `!(A || B || C)` is true only if all the variables are false.